# Polynomial regression in machine learning coursera

Tags: machine-learning, regression

While going through Andrew NG's Coursera course on machine learning . I found this particular thing that prices of a house might goes down after certain value of x in Quadratic regression equation. Can anyone explain why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrew Ng is trying to show that a Quadratic function doesn't really make sense to represent the price of houses.

This what the graph of a quadratic function might look like --> [image: Quadratic equation - ax^2 + bx + c]

*The values of a, b and c were chosen randomly for this example.*

As you can see in the figure, the graph first rises to a maximum and then begins to dip. This isn't representative of the real-world since the price of a house wouldn't normally come down with an increasingly larger house.

He recommends that we use a different polynomial function to represent this problem better, such as the cubic function.

[image: Cubic equation - ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d]

*The values of a, b, c and d were chosen randomly for this example.*

In reality, we would use a different method altogether for choosing the best polynomial function to fit a problem. We would try different polynomial functions on a cross-validation dataset and have an algorithm choose the best suited one. We could also manually chose a polynomial function for a dataset if we already know the trend that our data would follow (due to prior mathematical or physical knowledge).

Comment: I'm happy that it helped :)